# WCF Service to receive XML message

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to create a WCF service that accepts an XML message that interoperates with a non MS consumer. Now, I could expose a method that accepts a string and then handle the XML from that point onwards. Is there a better approach than using a string parameter?

Thanks

Comment: yes - receive parameters and objects representing that XML message, instead of the raw message itself......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `XmlNode` parameter.

Comment: Would I not then have to use Data Contracts? I just want to be able to receive any kind of XML and then perform XML and schema validation after receiving the XML.

Comment: I dont think so - just use an XmlNode in place of a string.

Comment: You end up with the following error

Type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XmlElement or an XElement parameter.

Use XmlElement if you want to use the System.Xml namespace to process the XML. Use XElement if you want to use LINQ to XML and the System.Xml.Linq namespace.

--Jacob