# Transfer XML between systems with Biztalk and WCF

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I have system A which produces an xml-file and system B which takes the file. How can I implement this exchange using Biztalk with WCF?

Comment: Elaborate your question, what kind of interfaces do system A and B offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible different solutions as I see it and it basically comes down to how typed you WCF service needs to be.

Do you need to transform you message into a new format? Or are you planning to use other features in BizTalk as content based routing etc? Are you at all interested in the content of the message while in BizTalk are you OK with just passing it thru?

If you are looking for a solution with the capabilities as described above you'll need to get the schema for the XML message you want to receive into WCF service and publish that service. Once the message is in BizTalk it's then typed and you can do what ever with it using BizTalk.

If you however just want to pass it thru you could just publish a service that received as message of type XML document and pass that thru. [Here's](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/four-ways-to-accept-any-xml-data-into-biztalk-web-services/) a good post describing the a few different techniques to create a generic service accepting any XML as input.

Comment: in one case I should transform a message and in another case I shouldn't.

Comment: How to implement a service that takes an XML message and which works with Biztalk? I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900930/wcf-service-to-receive-xml-message) but I'm not sure if it's suitable for using it with Biztalk because as far as I understand WCF-service for Biztalk uses XSD schemas as types that service can work with, am I right?

Comment: Updated post with link to post on a generic service accepting any type of XML data